# How to declare a <vector> object and use push_back inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

I'm trying to build a class named "Tombola" which should contain as private variable an empty vector. This should be filled at runtime through the class member Tombola.estrai(), which generates a random number and insert it inside the vector named "order" by the method order.push_back(number). This is the class definition in the `tombola.h` header:

```
#ifndef TOMBOLA_H
#define TOMBOLA_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Tombola {
    private:
        bool on_off[90];
        int tabellone[9][10];
        int x_max = 9;
        int y_max = 10;
        vector<int> order;
     public:
        Tombola();
        ~Tombola();
        void nuovo();
        int estrai();
        bool completato();
        void stampa();
        void stampa_tab();
};

#endif
```

And this is the implementation of constructor/destructor and Tombola::estrai() inside `tombola.cc`:

```
#include "tombola.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Tombola::Tombola () {
    vector<int> ord;
    order = ord;   
    int z=1;
    for(int i=0;i<90;i++)   {
        on_off[i] = false;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<=x_max;j++)  {
        for (int k=0;k<=y_max;k++) {
            tabellone[j][k] = z;
            z++;
        }
    }
}


Tombola::~Tombola() {
    cout << "Tombola is destroyed" << endl;
}

int Tombola::estrai()  {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int estrazione = int(ceil(rand()/double(RAND_MAX)*90));
    on_off[estrazione]==true;
    order.push_back(estrazione);
    return order.back();
}
```

and this is the call to the method in the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "tombola.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main () {
   Tombola natale;
   cout << natale.estrai();
}
```

When I compile the program everything goes fine, but when I execute the `main` I get a **segmentation fault error** which seems to be due to some sort of allocation error when trying to store the item inside the `order` vector, as reported by the debugger. Could someone explain to me how to solve the error and why the error occours? Thank you.

Comment: Change your `for(int j=0;j<=x_max;j++)` to `for(int j=0;j<x_max;j++)` to avoid out-of-bounds access to the arrays (and same for the inner loop).

Comment: These two lines in the constructor are unnecessary: `vector<int> ord; order = ord;`

Comment: on_off[estrazione]==true; just checks if the 2 things equals. If you want to set it `true` use `=` not `==`

Comment: Also, `using namespace std` in a header file is a bad idea, as it opens the door for a range of significant problems in all source files (e.g. broken build due to ambiguity) that `#include` it.   Although it involves more typing, use fully qualified names (e.g. `std::vector`) in header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of segmentation fault is in the constructor. You have to change `for(int j=0;j<=x_max;j++)` to `for(int j=0;j<x_max;j++)` in order not to cross the bounds of the array.

```
for(int j=0;j<x_max;j++)  {
    for (int k=0;k<y_max;k++) {
        tabellone[j][k] = z;
        z++;
    }
}
```

However, there are also some minor issues in the code that are worth being mentioned

- declaring default-initialized `ord` vector and assigning it to `order` is pointless because `order` is already default-initialized.(See member initializer list for more information).
- `using namespace std;` in a header file is a terrible idea, because if you had a large codebase, and had multiple source files where you want to include that header, everywhere the `using` statement will be applied, which probably is not desired.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure the error was due to the vector declaration that I forgot to check the rest. Also you've been clear about the minor issues.